Black hole radiating massive particles
Is it sensible to write the metric for a black hole that emits radiation that is composed of massive particles as
$$ds^2 = -\left(1-\frac{2M(t)}{r}\right)dt^2 + \frac{dr^2}{\left(1-\frac{2M(t)}{r}\right)}+ r^2d\Omega_{S^2}^2.$$
This is very similar to the Vaidya metric but that metric is for black holes that emit radiation composed of massless particles hence it has $M(u)$ instead of $M(t)$ and the metric is also written in the null-time coordinates appropriately. Can someone explain if such a metric above makes sense or the interpretation I have given it makes sense?

Notwithstanding the metric, by what mechanism do you think a black hole could generate massive particles? e.g. to generate an electron, we might have $\gamma\gamma \rightarrow e^-e^+$, but where should this interaction take place, inside or outside the blackhole, and where could the $\gamma \gamma$ ingredients be coming from?

@James You can write down Hawking radiation-type calculations for massive particles. This does lead to a non-trivial spectrum (Also non S-wave sectors of e.g. rotating b.h have an effective mass generated by the angular momentum quantum number)

@ThomasTappeiner You know any references that has done such a calculation?

I think Modeling Black Hole Evaporation by Fabbri & Navarro-salas should contain some information on this if I remember correctly (don't have the book on by phone so haven't checked today)

@James Don Page calculated electron-positron emission from a Schwarzschild hole in 1977. See https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.16.2402 The Hawking mechanism applies to all particles.

@Have you checked that your metric satisfies the non-static Einstein field equations? I do not think it does.

@JanG Neither does the Vaidya metric

M is not only a function of t but also r since the evaporated mass or energy can only fly away with finite speed, so you need an M(t,r) instead of an M(t), see Vaidya Spacetime in the Diagonal Coordinates and Global geometry of the Vaidya spacetime, although they don't really present their result in an elegant way.

@Yukterez Yeah I also thought of making it a function of $r$ as well but I wanted to retain the simplicity of the vaidya metric because in that metric $M$ is just the function of the null time coordinate. But I guess this complexity is inescapable.

First of all, “a black hole that emits radiation” should properly be called a white hole.
Second, no, the proposed metric cannot be thought as corresponding to a white hole radiating massive particles. This is because hypersurface on which the parameter $M$ is constant (which is a hypersurface $t=\mathrm {const}$) is spacelike in the outside the horizon region.
Interestingly, in the interior region $t=\mathrm {const}$ is actually a world-surface of a massive dust shell falling into the black hole (or being emitted by a white hole) with zero  energy, so there OP's metric works.
So, to obtain the needed metric in the outer region one has to analytically continue OP's original expression across white hole's past horizon e.g. using one of many horizon penetrating coordinates generalized to a varying $M$ parameter.
Alternatively, one could use a model of accreting black hole metric from this paper and do a time reversal. The case of zero energy at infinity dust matter is section VI. Both routes should produce the same spacetime.

I meant a black hole emitting Hawking radiation. But ok.

What is “time reversal” in curved spacetimes? For example, reversing the Schwarzschild $t$ coordinate inside the horizon evidently is not “time reversal”, because this coordinate is spacelike.

@safesphere If the manifold is time orientable, we can consistently pick time orientation, basically an arrow of time at each point of spacetime. Manifold is time oriented after we made this choice. Time reversal means we choose the opposite orientation. This does not depend on the choice of coordinates. But if the manifold is nice enough it can have a time coordinate for which time reversal corresponds to $t \to -t$.

Thanks, this helps. However, in the Schwarzschild coordinates, my spatial motion inside the horizon during a radial fall is along spacelike $t$.  Once I crossed, I can fire my spaceship engines against my direction and reverse my movement in $t$ to the opposite. This however would not reverse my time, so I would continue falling in. Then how is the reversal of $t$ is the time reversal that you describe?

@safesphere Schwarzschild time $t$, obviously is the wrong choice for that since $dt$ is spacelike inside horizon. A good coordinate for maximally extended Schwarzschild spacetime is the $T$ coordinate of Kruskal-Szekeres metric. Ingoing generalized G-P coordinate $t$ like those used in a paper I cited above would also work for collapsing spacetimes (that do not have white hole regions)
